# How do I filter my result by a month and a year that I input?

Tags: python, django, filter

I'm trying to filter an order to get the most sold pizza in a given month and year.
This is the code so far but I don't know how to configure it so it would search depending on the month and year I type and not a fixed one.

For example, if I type my query as month 03 and year 2021 then I should get my object. How do I manage to do that?

Fecha is the date that's defined in the models as fecha = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

```
obj = Order.objects.filter(fecha__month=month, fecha__year=year).annotate(Max('pizzas__cant')).order_by('-pizzas__cant__max').first()
```

This is the model:

```
class Pizzas(models.Model):
   nombre = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
   cant = models.IntegerField(default=0)

   def __str__(self):
       return self.nombre

class Pedido(models.Model):
   fecha = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
   email = models.EmailField(max_length=200, null=True)
   telefono = models.IntegerField(null=True)
   pizzas = models.ManyToManyField('Pizzas', related_name='pedidos', blank=True)
   cantidad = models.IntegerField(default=0)

   def __str__(self):
       return self.email
```

Comment: Can you add your models to the question

Comment: You have the `year` variable, right?

Comment: @JPG That's the thing, I don't. What I want is to use the year and month that's in "fecha" that's my datefield so that I can type a month and year and get my object.

Comment: @IainShelvington I added it.

Comment: @satoru can you be slightly clearer on what your desired output is? Given a year and month you want to return a `Pizzas` object that was sold the most times in that timeframe?

Comment: @IainShelvington Yes, given a year and a month I want it to return a pizzas object (with its name and the quantity) that was sold the most in that timeframe, say if I have the mont march and year 2021 and there's one order that sold 4 pizzas type1 and 2 pizzas type2 and then another order that sold 3 pizzas type2 , it'd return the 4 pizzas type 1. I hope that's clearer.

Comment: @satoru where is the number of pizzas sold for each pizza type in an order stored?

Comment: @IainShelvington I only have the pizzas field that itself has the field name and quantity of pizzas. I'm not sure how to add the quantity of sold pizzas in the order model.

Comment: @satoru there's a through table where the quantity is stored? Can you add the Pizza model and through table to the question

Comment: @IainShelvington I added the model but I am not sure what a though table is, I'm afraid. I'm very new at this.

Comment: @satoru in your example, wouldn't you want 5 pizzas type 2 since that's the most sold pizza? Or are you just looking for the single biggest sale?

Comment: @IainShelvington You are right, I got it mixed up, it'd be 5 pizzas type 2.

Comment: @satoru I think you are going to have to change your models, at the moment I don't think you have any way of determining the quantity of each pizza sold in each sale. Adding a through model with the quantity I think would help, I have some code that seems to work, are you able to change the models?

Comment: @IainShelvington Oh, I see. Yes, I can change the models.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to achieve what I think you are looking for using a slightly different model structure

```
class Pizza(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)


class Sale(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField()
    pizzas = models.ManyToManyField(Pizza, through='SalePizzaThrough', related_name='sales')


class SalePizzaThrough(models.Model):
    pizza = models.ForeignKey(Pizza, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    sale = models.ForeignKey(Sale, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
```

`SalePizzaThrough` is the through table used for the many to many between `Sale` and `Pizza` and stores the quantity of pizzas sold in that sale

I recreated the scenario given by you above and the following code creates the data and shows the query that can be used to get the result

```
import datetime
from django.db.models import Sum

pizza_1 = Pizza.objects.create(name='Pizza 1')
pizza_2 = Pizza.objects.create(name='Pizza 2')

sale_1 = Sale.objects.create(date=datetime.date(2021, 3, 1))
SalePizzaThrough.objects.create(sale=sale_1, pizza=pizza_1, quantity=4)
SalePizzaThrough.objects.create(sale=sale_1, pizza=pizza_2, quantity=2)

sale_2 = Sale.objects.create(date=datetime.date(2021, 3, 1))
SalePizzaThrough.objects.create(save=sale_2, pizza=pizza_2, quantity=3)

most_sold_pizza = Pizza.objects.filter(
    sales__date__year=2021,
    sales__date__month=3
).annotate(
    total=Sum('salepizzathrough__quantity')
).order_by('-total').first()
```

Comment: Thank you. This seems good but since I changed the model, I get  "__str__ returned non-string (type NoneType) " in the Salepizzathrough model for some reason.